# What is the role of +n+ inside {0,"+n+"}

Tags: c#

```
        int n=6;
        string a=null;
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
            Console.WriteLine("{0,"+n+"}",a+="#");
        }
```

Any one can explain what it (`+n+`)
actually doing in this code?
Why it's not printing the value of n instead spaces.

**I am new and i'm learning c#.**

Comment: String concatenation + old formatting style.

Comment: It concatinates the number n into the string. + [Composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting), specifically [Alignment Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#alignment-component)

Comment: why not just try it out by debugging?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("{0,5}", "#");` prints `"     #"` This code is putting the value of `n` where I have a `5`.

Comment: Also see the [Control Spacing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0#control-spacing) documentation for string formatting.

Comment: The "duplicate" is talking about string concatenation, but this question is really about string formatting.

Comment: Ah, and the _reason_ why concatenation is used is that the author obviously wanted to change only one single place in the code to scale the output.

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```cs
"{0,"+n+"}"
```

Can be divided into few parts:

`"{0,"` is a string literal. It's a string containing 3 characters: the bracket, the zero and the comma.

`+n` appends the current value of the int variable `n` to the previous string.

`+"}"` appends a string literal `"}"` (a string with only one character, the bracket) to the previous string.

For example, if `n` equals 6, then the expression will produce a `{0,6}` string.